# Excel VBA Determining Mass of Truck Shipments

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2013

I have a system where I have a list of data from a truck scale reading the weight of a truck on a scale. This data ranges from -30,000lbs or so due to the scale being tared but truckless, to 40,000lbs with a full and tared truck on it. My task is to determine the total weight that has left our facility via truck. The problem is some days only a few trucks leave our facility and others a dozen leave, all with slightly different weights.

The graph of these weights looks like a saw tooth pattern. It is a largely negative value (due to tare), quickly reaches approximately zero as a truck pulls onto the scale, and slowly builds to a final weight. After the final weight is reached the weight quickly goes back to the largely negative value as the truck pulls away.

My idea on how to approach this is look for where the data is less than zero and return the max weight of the sensor between zeros. If the max weight is above some noise filter value (say, 5000lbs) then add the max weight to some counter. In theory, not bad, in practice, a bit out of my league.

Here's my code so far, as I know I need to show my effort so far. I recommend ignoring it as it's mostly just a failed start after a few days of restarting work.

```
Public Function TruckLoad(rngData As Range)
Dim intCount As Integer
intCount = 0
For Each cell In rngData
    intCount = intCount + 1
Next cell
Dim n As Integer
n = 1
Dim x As Integer
x = 1
Dim arr() As Double
For i = 1 To intCount
    If rngData(i, 1) < 0 Then
        arr(n) = x
        n = n + 1
        x = x + 1
    Else
        x = x + 1
    End If
Next
TruckLoad = arr(1)

End Function
```

If anyone could give me advice on how to proceed it would be extremely valuable. I'm not a computer programmer outside of the very basics.

Edit: Sorry, I should have said this initially. I can't post the entirety of the raw sample data but I can post a photo of a graph. There is a degree to which I can't post publicly (not that you can do anything particularly nefarious with the data, it's a corporate rule).

www.imgur.com/a/LGQY9

Comment: Some sample data would be very useful too!

Comment: Hello Jethro, can you post up some sample data, it could be very useful for us to help you. Perhaps even a picture of the worksheet you are working with. Your are close to the problem, so it is easy for you to conceptualize, but we need a little more help from you, to help you.

Comment: Are you looking at a contiguous series of data of more than one truck like: `-4,-4,-3,-2,-3,-4,-4,-1,0,1,2,3,2,1,0,-4,-4,-3,-2,-3,-4,-4,-4,-4,-3,-2,-3,-4,-4,0,2,4,5,4,2,0` - and you are just looking for the `3` and the `5` ?

Comment: Robin, spot on. Basically there's a lot of garbage data at the lower end (mine is like -30,000 and yours is like -4, same difference) and a bit of good data near the top (40,000 and 5). I need the highest value of each discrete "peak" summed. In your case, there are 2 peaks, one with a max at 3 and one with a max at 5. The function I wish to create would return 8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My understanding of the data is in line with Robin's comment.  There are a couple of ways to solve this problem.  I've written a function loops through data range looking for the 'next zero' in the data set, and calculates the max value between the current row and the row that the 'next zero' is in.  If the max value is above the value of your noise filter, the value will be added to the running total.

```
Option Explicit

Private Const NOISE_FILTER As Double = 5000

Public Function TruckLoad(rngData As Range) As Double

    Dim r As Integer
    Dim runningTruckLoad As Double
    Dim maxLoadReading As Double
    Dim nextZeroRow As Integer

    For r = 1 To rngData.Rows.Count

        nextZeroRow = FindNextZeroRow(r, rngData)

        maxLoadReading = Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(Range(rngData.Cells(r, 1), rngData.Cells(nextZeroRow, 1)))

        If maxLoadReading > NOISE_FILTER Then
            runningTruckLoad = runningTruckLoad + maxLoadReading
        End If

        r = nextZeroRow 'skip the loop counter ahead to our new 0 row

    Next r

    TruckLoad = runningTruckLoad

End Function

Private Function FindNextZeroRow(startRow As Integer, searchRange As Range) As Integer

    Dim nextZeroRow As Range

    Set nextZeroRow = searchRange.Find(0, searchRange.Rows(startRow))

    If nextZeroRow.Row < startRow Then 'we've hit the end of the data range
        FindNextZeroRow = startRow
    ElseIf nextZeroRow.Value <> 0 Then  'we've found a data point with a zero in it, not interested in this row
        FindNextZeroRow = FindNextZeroRow(nextZeroRow.Row, searchRange)
    Else
        FindNextZeroRow = nextZeroRow.Row 'we've found our next zero data point
    End If

End Function
```

Comment: Seems to work well, though I seriously think my data is bad to the point where I'll need to massage your code to get it to work. A rough estimate puts us at around 900,000lbs according to the entirety of the graph. My inventory guy says it should be around 300,000lbs (not sure how much stock I put in this, he's crazy busy and I didn't ask any followup questions). Your code is 214,000lbs. I'm not willing to definitively say this is the answer until I get a result that is more consistent across the board (not trying to insult your code if it came across like that).

Comment: No offense taken.  Depending on the data, there can certainly be some scenarios that my function hasn't accounted for.  Perhaps there is a scenario where trucks are measured within succession, and the scale never measures below 0 (or the noise factor), for example.  Good luck, and feel free to ask for help in accounting for any specific scenarios you encounter.

Comment: I think I solved it, I just looked for where the weight dropped significantly (5000lbs or more in 15s but I'll tweak this) and took the max value of the 10 previous cells. I summed these max weights and got a touch over a million pounds, compared to my estimate of just over 900,000lbs I'm happy with this, and I already can see some errors that'll bring these numbers closer. Your code can definitely still be useful, even if only for documentation. Can I get your ok in including it in my final product? It's for purely internal use and I can credit you however you'd like.

Comment: I seek no credit. That code belongs to the world and you can use it however you'd like. I'm happy it helped you find your solution.